# MIPS - XOR of 2 binary number returns non-binary number

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm doing a simple XOR statement of 2 binary numbers just to test the XOR function but it gives me a weird result.

Program:

```
li $t0, 10101
li $t1, 11101
li $t2, 0

move $a0, $t2
li $v0,1
syscall

la $a0, endl
li $v0,4
syscall

xor $t2, $t0, $t1

move $a0, $t2
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,10   # Exit
syscall         # Bye!
```

This is the result:

```
0
3112
```

Last time i checked the XOR of 10101 and 11101=01000, NOT some base 10 number 3112.

Comment: Last time I checked (just right now), 10101 XOR 11101 indeed yields 3112. All in decimal, of course, just like your code.

Comment: How do i perform it in binary in MIPS?

Comment: What's a non-binary number? (Or a binary number, for that matter.)

Comment: You did perform it in binary, there's no other way to xor. You just read the result (and the inputs) incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the assembler supports input of binary constants depends on which assembler you're using. For example, SPIM's assembler does *not* support the `0b` prefix for binary numbers.

If your assembler doesn't support binary constants you'll have to write the numbers in a base that the assembler *does* understand, i.e.:

```
li $t0, 0x15
li $t1, 0x1D
```

or

```
li $t0, 21
li $t1, 29
```

To get the output printed in binary you'll have to generate a string with a base-2 textual representation of the value yourself, which you then can print with syscall 4 (if you're using SPIM). If you're using MARS you can print values directly in binary using syscall 35.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you load the values in decimal:

```
li $t0, 10101
li $t1, 11101
```

xor(10101d, 11101d) = 3112d.

Comment: How do i perform it in binary in MIPS?

Comment: It depends on the assembler you are using. See Michael's answer.